# Remove multiple index.php instances from url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know how to remove index.php from a rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But I don't know what to do when I see this in my 404 logs:

```
video/index.php 
video/index.php/index.php 
video/index.php/index.php/index.php 
video/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php
```

Is there a way to remove all of these without having to spell each one out? Like can I loop through a rewrite rule to keep removing index.php until it's gone?

Thanks very much,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. Weird that people actually request that kind of URI.

Give this a try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This should repetitively remove any `index.php` mentions from the end of the `REQUEST_URI`, and redirect to the correct one. Note, however, that it'll redirect every single time until it's gone.

Also note, I haven't tested it yet, as my PC is currently not working (though the rule seems basic enough to share). Please let me know if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Oh, and you'll want to make this the first rule, just after your conditions.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm. And I actually have some even crazier urls (I think some script is causing it, whether on my site or on some kind of scraping site) such as http://www.mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com/video/video1/index.php/index.php/index.php so I also added this in addition to your code and it seems to be working: RewriteRule ^(.*)www\.mydomain\.com\/(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L,NC]